# Microsoft Word language change while Typing

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an issue with MS Office 2016 where it will sometimes change the language that is entered into a document from English to Greek to French and I cannot get it to go back to English.  I originally had this issue with MS Office 2010...and I found out that a Keyboard shortcut can be used to alternate the language that is entered into a document.  Unfortunately...I do not remember that shortcut and have tried some of the more unusual combinations as I seem to remember it wasn't a commonly-used shortcut.

As of this moment...the most reliable way to reset the language is to close the document and reopen it.  I have tried some Google and SO searches...but all I have seen is about changing programming languages, not the textual language that is entered into a document.

Thank you.

Comment: In case you're on Windows your issue could also be that you unintentionally switch keyboard layout by pressing `ALT` + `Shift` keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're on Windows your issue could be that you unintentionally switch keyboard layout by pressing

```
ALT + Shift
```

keyboard shortcut. This will also switch the language in Microsoft Word (tested in Microsoft Word 2010).

As stated this is not actually a feature of Microsoft Word but more of Windows.